# fgetcsv return special charterer when try to read persion language file

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv, csv-import

I'm working on CSV import / export system in [persian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_language) language.

I have created script for export file. For I have used following header in php:

```
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
```

but when I try to read exported csv file or any other csv file using `fgetcsv` function it's return:

```
???? ?????? ????? ????? ? ???? ?????????? ?????? ?? ??? ????? ???? ??? ?????? ?????? ???
```

Instead of persian language string. I have used following code for read csv file:

```
if (($handle = fopen($csvfile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $max_line_length = defined('MAX_LINE_LENGTH') ? MAX_LINE_LENGTH : 10000;
    $header = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length);
    $header_colcount = count($header);
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length)) !== FALSE) {
        $row_colcount = count($row);
        if ($row_colcount == $header_colcount) {
            $entry = array_combine($header, $row);
            $csv[] = $entry;
        }
        else {
            error_log("csvreader: Invalid number of columns at line " . ($rowcount + 2) . " (row " . ($rowcount + 1) . "). Expected=$header_colcount Got=$row_colcount");
          return null;
        }
        $rowcount++;
    }
    //echo "Totally $rowcount rows found\n";
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your fgetcsv code.

Comment: Check file encoding. I had situation when text in English was shown as some Japanese symbols.

Comment: @deceze thanks for replay. i have added code. please check

Comment: @justinas it's UTF-8. and i think it's ok.